# Strange integral result

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

Consider the following integral,
$$\mathrm{I} =  \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{d}{dx}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx$$

We can do this in two ways,

***First***
Using the fact that the antiderivative of $\frac{d}{dx}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is simply $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, it reduces to

$$ \mathrm{I} = \tan^{-1}(1) - \tan^{-1}(-1) = \frac{\pi}{4} - \left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Another way to this is using that $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \cot^{-1}x$

Also notice that I've not balanced range (but it won't impact the integral)

$$\mathrm{I} = \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{d}{dx}\cot^{-1}(x)dx$$

Use the fact that you know the derivative of $\cot^{-1}x$,

$$ =  -\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{1 + x^2} = -\left[\tan^{-1}(x)\right]_{-1}^{1}$$
$$ =  -\left[\tan^{-1}(1) - \tan^{-1}(-1)\right] = -\left[\frac{\pi}{4} - \left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right]$$

$$\mathrm{I} = -\frac{\pi}{2}$$

One method gives $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and other gives $-\frac{\pi}{2}$. Strange...
(Please explain this sorcery)

**Notice that $tan^{-1} x$ is an inverse trigonometric function**

Comment: I think the integral $I$ is improper because $\frac d{dx} \tan^{-1}(1/x)$ is undefined at $x= 0$.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cotan(1%2Fx) picture is worth a thousand words

Comment: Sorry but I think you're confusing $\tan^{-1}x$ with $\cot x$. We use this notation for inverse trigonometric function in our country.

Comment: Also wolframalpha says that $\mathrm{I}$ exists and is equal to $-\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Since $\tan^{-1}(1/x)$ has jump of size $\pi$ at the origin, its derivative (in distribution sense) should contain the point mass term $\pi \delta(x)$ as well as the usual term $-1/(1+x^2)$. In order for your FTC-like computation to be true, the differentiation should be understood in distributional sense, and then the extra term $\pi\delta(x)$ justifies your first computation.

Answer (score 3):

The first integral is incorrect because of the interval of integration $0\in(-1,1)$

The integral instead should be:

$$\int \dfrac{d}{dx} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx=-\tan^{-1}(x)+C$$

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: My apologies. I forgot to exclude the interval of integration when typing the integral. However, I did not mention anything about the constant of integration. My goal was to only show the general integral.

Comment: $-\tan^{-1}(x)|^1_{-1}=-\tan^{-1}(1)+\tan^{-1}(-1)=-\pi/2$

Comment: This integral clearly does not produce the same conclusion as the asker. Furthermore, I did note that the integral is incorrect because of the *interval of integration* where $0\in(-1,1)$.

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry I didn't see the negative sign and the fact that you had $x$ instead of $\frac1x$. But you should add explanation of why your answer is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback on the answer but in the future, please do not lash out at a person just trying to answer a question.

Comment: Well, your first post had both integration limits and a free variable on the right, so it was obviously wrong and I didn't look too carefully. My mistake was in not looking again after you had fixed that.

Answer (score 3):

The first way you computed the integral was not correct, because the integral is improper.

\begin{align*}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{d}{dx}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx &= \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\left[\int_{-1}^{-\varepsilon}\frac{d}{dx}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx + \int_{\varepsilon}^{1}\frac{d}{dx}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx\right]\\
&=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \left[\tan^{-1}\left(-\frac1{\varepsilon}\right) - \tan^{-1}(-1) + \tan^{-1}(1) - \tan^{-1}\left(\frac1\varepsilon\right)\right]\\
&=-\frac\pi2-\left(-\frac\pi4\right) + \frac\pi4-\frac\pi2\\
& = -\frac\pi2
\end{align*}

Comment: Sorry for poking this old question, but what if the limits are both positive or both negative, then we won't have to jump at zero and it should still be defined. $\int_{b}^{a}\frac{d}{dx}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx$, where $ab > 0$

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly integrate as it is discontineous at $x=0$. So break the integral in the form 
$$I=\int_{-1}^{0^-}\frac{d}{dx}(tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{x}))dx+\int_{0^+}^{1}\frac{d}{dx}(tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{x}))dx$$ which is equal to 
$$I=[(-\frac{\pi}{2})-(-\frac{\pi}{4})]+[\frac {\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{2}]=-\frac{\pi}{2}$$ which is the correct answer.

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $\tan^{-1}(\frac1x)$ is **not** the anti-derivative of $\frac{d}{dx}(\tan^{-1}(\frac1x))$. Why? Because $\tan^{-1}(\frac1x)$ is undefined when $x = 0$, not to say have a derivative there. So the claim only holds for $x \ne 0$. Because of that, one cannot use the theorem that $\int_a^b f'(x)\ dx = f(b)-f(a)$ for any function $f$ that has integrable derivative on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Jackson has already shown how to correctly compute the answer so I'm not repeating it.